# How to change this procedure from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am using sql server 2008 in production. Below is my stored procedure which is working fine on SQL Server 2012 but gives a fetch error in SQL Server 2008. The reason is `fetch` is not built in SQL Server 2008 but it is available in SQL Server 2012. Help me with converting this script to work with SQL Server 2008.

```
Create PROCEDURE sp_LoadSponsorsListofDonorsforReminder
    @pageSize int,
    @Offset int,
    @TotalRecords int out
as
BEGIN
    SELECT max(cd.OID) as OID, max(cd.DonationId) as DonationId,
           max(cd.DonorId) as DonorId, 
           max(Concat(do.FIRSTNAME,' ', do.LASTNAME)) as Donor_Name,
           max(do.PHONENUMBER) as PHONENUMBER,
           max(do.MOBILENUMBER) as MOBILENUMBER, max(do.ADDRESS) as ADDRESS, 
           max(do.EMAIL) as EMAIL, max(cd.PaidUpTo) as PaidUpTo, 
           max(cd.StartDate) as StartDate, max(ca.ChildCode) as ChildCode, 
           max(concat (ca.FirstName,' ', ca.LastName)) as Child_Name, 
           max(org.ORGANIZATION_NAME) as Village, 
           max(d.DonationDate) as DonationDate, 
           max(r.ReminderOneDate) as ReminderOneDate 
    FROM child_sponsorship cd
        inner join donations d 
           ON cd.DonationId = d.OID
        inner JOIN donor do 
           ON cd.DonorId = do.OID
        inner join child_admission ca 
           ON cd.ChildId = ca.OID
        inner join organization org
           ON do.ORGANIZATION = org.OID
        left join Reminder_Information r
           ON cd.DonorId = r.DonorId  
    WHERE d.DonationDate < DATEADD(day, -365, GETDATE()) AND
          cd.DonorId <> 1174 AND
          cd.DonorId <> 1175
    GROUP by cd.childId
    ORDER By Max(d.DonationDate), max(cd.DonorId) desc
    OFFSET @Offset ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY
    SET @TotalRecords = (select count(*) from child_sponsorship WHERE 1=1);
END;
```

Comment: `CONCAT(a, ' ', b) == a + ' ' + b`

Comment: fetch also not working in sql server 2008

Comment: You would need to populate a temp table with an IDENTITY_column and use a combination of SELECT TOP [@pageSize] ..and use IDENTITY_column > [@Offset].in the WHERE clause

Comment: can you please change is @Mountaineer

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a ROW_NUMBER on the fly for your query. I'm not going to reproduce the entire thing here, but here is a simple example that uses the Products table from the Northwind sample database

```
DECLARE @pageNumber INT = 2, @pageSize INT = 6

SELECT ProductID,ProductName, UnitPrice
FROM 
(
    SELECT ProductID,ProductName, UnitPrice,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductID) AS rn
    FROM Products 
) AS P
WHERE P.rn BETWEEN ((@pageNumber-1)*@pageSize)+1 AND @pageSize*(@PageNumber)
```

The inner query produces the row number, the outer query gets the fields you want (i.e. without the row number). The inner query is where you put all the stuff you have above
The outer query is where you put your WHERE clause using AND to limit the value of P.rn

Answer (score 0):

Using the Product table from AdventureWorksLT2008R2 db as an example

```
DECLARE @pageSize int = 10,
        @Offset int = 20

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xRecords') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #xRecords
CREATE TABLE #xRecords(
     ID             INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_xRecords PRIMARY KEY
    ,ProductID      INT
    ,Name           NVARCHAR(50)
    ,ProductNumber  NVARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO #xRecords ( ProductID, Name, ProductNumber)
SELECT 
     ProductID
    ,Name
    ,ProductNumber
FROM
    [AdventureWorksLT2008R2].[SalesLT].[Product]

SELECT
    TOP (@pageSize) *
FROM
    #xRecords
WHERE
    ID > @Offset
```